# Ms-Access and using numbers to link forms

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010

I have a ms-access 2010 database.  I used autonumbers as my primary keys to link tables for my forms.  I am exporting the tables to sharepoint.  I can't use my autonumbers or primary keys anymore because sharepoint doesn't allow it.  I changed my autonumbers to just numbers.  This is where I have the problem.  I have a form called `Shipping` with a shipping number field.  I have a `ShippingDetails` subform with a shipping details ID field that is linked to the `Shipping` form with the shipping number field.  I need to make the shipping number and shipping details ID increment by 1.  I got the shipping number to increment by using the following code in the current event of the form:

```
If Me.NewRecord = True Then
   Me.ShippingNumber =Nz(DMax("ShippingNumber","Shipping"),x)+1
End If
```

`x` is the last shipping number in my form

I tried using the same code in my subform ShippingDetails current event with these changes:

```
If Me.NewRecord = True Then
   Me.DetailsID =Nz(DMax("DetailsID","qryShippingDetails"),x)+1
End If
```

`x` is the last details ID in my form.

The subform `ShippingDetails` is a datasheet view and the first record will increment the value but then each new record is a duplicate.  The details ID won't change.
I would appreciate any help you can give me.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to use `DMax` as well as the last details Id in your form? Does this mean that you can enter several details before they are inserted into the table? Otherwise `Nz(DMax("DetailsID","qryShippingDetails"),0)+1` would be sufficient.

I would adjust x each time

```
If Me.NewRecord Then
    x = Nz(DMax("DetailsID", "qryShippingDetails"), x) + 1
    Me.DetailsID = x
End If
```

Comment: Each detail record has to be entered individually into the table.  I found that code online and adapted it for my use.  I am not  a programmer.  I tried your code and it works for what I need.  Thank you for your help, Oliver.